# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

When I call a method from another class, I get the error:

> (TREAD) : EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Here my method in class A:

```
-(NSString*) parse: (NSString *) filePath
{
    ////do something
     codeWriter* cd;
     cd = [[codeWriter alloc]init];

    NSString* asmLine = [cd getAsmLine:lineContent]; ////here is my problem
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand what the error is?

Thanks

Comment: Is `codewriter` your own class?

Comment: Please provide relevant amount of source code to understand the context.

Comment: yes , codeWriter is my own class. what to provide for you ?

Comment: What's 'lineContent' and does it get initialized anywhere?

Comment: yes, lineContent is a string (line in file) , i read from some file tha all line . and i send the line in file to method getAsmLine in CodeWriterClass.      the Method: getAsmLine- i send the line, and get translate in ASM (Assembly).

Answer (score 1):

The error means you are attempting to access a bad patch of memory.

Where does the array "linecontent" get initialized? I imagine that "linecontent" array is not still in memory by the time the `getAsmLine:` method is called

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is my own class.

The method that i call in class codeWriter:

```
-(NSString *)getAsmLine : (NSArray*) line {
    /////do something
    return string; }
```